ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor Server App - Cookie can not be set
I'm having trouble with my application. Even though the user check is completed successfully, no cookies are being added to the browser. I have tried with many users and browsers but I couldn't get any results. Please help me with this issue, thank you.
Communication Flow:
login.razor:
Captures user login credentials and sends a request to AuthController via AuthService.
AuthService.cs:
Forwards the user credentials received from the login.razor component to AuthController.
Receives the token information from AuthController and checks the cookie added to the browser.
AuthController.cs:
Verifies the user's credentials using SignInManager.
Once the user is authenticated, generates a JWT token using TokenService.
Stores the generated token as a cookie using CookieService.
Returns the token along with an OK response to AuthService.
TokenService.cs:
Invoked by AuthController to generate a JWT token.
After creating the token, it returns it to AuthController.
CookieService.cs:
Invoked by AuthController to store the generated token as a cookie.
Logs any errors during the cookie operations via ILogger.
Login.razor
@page "/login"
@using System.Net.Http.Headers

@inject AuthService AuthService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<EditForm Model="@loginModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleLogin">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.UserName" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Password" type="password" />
    <div class="text-danger">@errorMessage</div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private LoginViewModel loginModel = new LoginViewModel();
    private string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    private async Task HandleLogin()
    {
        var response = await AuthService.Login(loginModel);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var token = AuthService.GetAuthToken();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                var client = AuthService.GetHttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
            Console.WriteLine(token);

        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}

AuthService.cs
public class AuthService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly HttpClientHandler _httpClientHandler;
    private readonly ILogger<AuthService> _logger; 

    public AuthService(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger<AuthService> logger)
    {
        _httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseCookies = true,
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
        };

        _httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpClientHandler);
        _logger = logger; 

        if (_httpClient.BaseAddress == null)
        {
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7025/");
        }
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Login isteği gönderiliyor.");
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/login", model);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Login succes.");
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Login error. Durum kodu: {StatusCode}", response.StatusCode);
            }

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during the login request.");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public string GetAuthToken()
    {
        try
        {
            var cookies = _httpClientHandler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(_httpClient.BaseAddress);
            var authToken = cookies["authToken"]?.Value;

            if (authToken != null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("authToken cookie received: {Token}", authToken);
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("authToken cookie not found.");
            }

            return authToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while retrieving the authToken cookie.");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        return _httpClient;
    }
}

CookieService.cs
public class CookieService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly ILogger<CookieService> _logger;

    public CookieService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<CookieService> logger)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void SetAuthTokenCookie(string token)
    {
        var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = true, 
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
            IsEssential = true
        };

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("authToken", token, cookieOptions);
        _logger.LogInformation("The authToken cookie was added successfully.");
    }

    public string GetAuthTokenCookie()
    {
        var token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["authToken"];
        if (token == null)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("The authToken cookie was not found.");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("authToken cookie received: {Token}", token);
        }
        return token;
    }

    public void RemoveAuthTokenCookie()
    {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("authToken");
        _logger.LogInformation("The authToken cookie was deleted.");
    }
}

AuthController.cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly TokenService _tokenService;
    private readonly CookieService _cookieService;
    private readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;

    public AuthController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, TokenService tokenService, CookieService cookieService, ILogger<AuthController> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _tokenService = tokenService;
        _cookieService = cookieService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var token = _tokenService.GenerateToken(model.UserName);
                _cookieService.SetAuthTokenCookie(token);
                return Ok(new { token });
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Invalid login attempt for user: {UserName}", model.UserName);
                return Unauthorized("Invalid login attempt.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during the login process.");
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
        }
    }
}

TokenService.cs
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public TokenService(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

public string GenerateToken(string userName)
{
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    };

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        signingCredentials: creds);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}

public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]);

    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };

    try
    {
        var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out _);
        return principal;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}

Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false; 
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CookieService>();
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
    };
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "auth_token"; 
    options.LoginPath = "/login"; 
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/access-denied"; 
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; 
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; 
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; 
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30); 
    options.SlidingExpiration = true; 
});
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("localhost")
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials();
        });
});
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();
string smtpServer = builder.Configuration["Email:SmtpServer"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(smtpServer), "SMTP Server is not configured.");
int smtpPort = int.TryParse(builder.Configuration["Email:SmtpPort"], out var port) ? port : 587;
string smtpUser = builder.Configuration["Email:SmtpUser"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(smtpUser), "SMTP User is not configured.");
string smtpPass = builder.Configuration["Email:SmtpPass"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(smtpPass), "SMTP Password is not configured.");

builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>(i =>
    new EmailSender(smtpServer, smtpPort, smtpUser, smtpPass));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RoleInitializer>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBootstrapBase, BootstrapBase>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<MenuService>();

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var roleInitializer = services.GetRequiredService<RoleInitializer>();
    await roleInitializer.InitializeAsync(
        services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(),
        services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>());
}

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseSession();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();


Why not use OIDC?

The current code usage is problematic and cannot be resolved.
Workaround
If you want to implement the current requirement in Login.razor, you can refer to the method in this answer. Otherwise, we will definitely encounter the error message: Headers are read-only, response has already started .
Best Practices
Create an authentication cookie

The initial code runs fine, but the following line does not work, and the custom authToken cannot be added. This method is wrong. Even if it can be added, we will encounter the error Headers are read-only, response has already started when we return to the Login.razor page code.

